# Notice to the administrator regarding downvoting of questions

Tags: discussion

I want to get it noticed by the administrator that our questions are getting downvoted which is debarring us from asking any further questions which is really creating constraints for us in our research work. I would request the administrator to remove this feature of debarring the person from asking further questions if their questions get downvoted. Any positive move in this regard will be highly appreciated.

How can I communicate to the administrator and brief him about the issue?

Comment: 1) The "administrator" is hands-off and won't help you. 2) This is not a research site.

Comment: You are entirely missing the point of this site. You ask crappy questions, you get downvoted. If you want a different concept, go elsewhere.

Comment: The downvotes could very well be earned. The question might not be well presented for any number of reasons. The notion is that one will take the opportunity to improve the question, or enquire into how to make a better question next time. The community decides, together, whether a question is a good one, and discourages other sorts of questions.

Comment: This kind of questions should be asked on meta, as Curd says. However, I don't think a lot of people will agree on what you say. This is by design. And guess what, **there are a lot of newcomers that don't get downvoted**. How do they achieve this? They ask good questions.

Comment: As @Curd said, this is a discussion for meta, but the way it normally works is: 1) You ask a question, 2) You attract downvotes, 3) You try to undertsnad what's wrong with your question, 4) You edit and improve your question, 5) Downvotes are removed and/or upvotes received. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Please read the [help] to understand how to ask good questions. If you indicate questions you have asked which attract downvotes, someone *might* look at the comments, and *might* try to explain why they attracted downvotes *if* they feel it is not clear enough. However, if the comments were clear, and the community feels the questions were downvoted for legitimate reasons, then you are probably trying to use this site in a way it is not intended to be used.

Comment: If you are asking questions poor enough to earn downvotes, your "research work" needs some re-evaluation. The "constraints" so created are that you must make some initial effort yourself, which is entirely appropriate.

Comment: READ THIS: If you are a newcomer and ask several questions which are all downvoted the system will not let you ask more questions until you improve the existing ones. A problem is that downvoters often do not come back and change their votes after a question is improved. IF you have improved a question you can use the "flag" button under the question to contact the administrators and tell them what you have done. Just contacting them with no improvements will not work.

Answer (score 16):

It sounds like you are complaining that you have been blocked from posting questions due to the ones you did post getting downvoted.

The site is working correctly.  There is nothing to fix.  The problem is not with the site, but with you writing bad questions.

When you write a bad question, it gets downvoted by the other users here.  If this happens too much, then the site blocks you from asking more questions.  This is because you have shown yourself to be a net negative, and the site is protecting itself from more of the same.  Complaining about the symptom won't help.  All you can do is address the root cause, which is the low quality of your questions.

From this question, I can see one possible reason for the downvotes is the rather annoying English.  I understand English is likely not your first language, and that you may be doing the best you can.  However, the world judges results, not effort.  It doesn't matter how you manage to write a good question, only that you do.  Put more effort into your writing or get someone else to do it for you.  However, if in the end you can't produce a English that isn't annoying to read, then you don't get to post here.

In addition to the question not being annoying to read, it must state the problem clearly, give pertinent information, be appropriate for the site, and otherwise follow the rules.  You should also be actively envolved with the question.  Often some clarification is needed, so people will ask questions in comments.  Address these promptly and directly, and add the additional information to the question.  Do not hide additional information in comments where it is easily skipped and possibly deleted after a while.

Clearly you need to **read the rules**.  I just noticed that this question was originally posted on the main site.  There is no excuse for that.  If you had bothered to understand how this site works before barging in an blurting out your question, you would have understood the difference between the main site and meta.

The ban you received seems completely justified.